# Is there a compilation time difference between #include <filename.h> and #include “path/to/file/filename.h”?

Tags: c++, compilation

It seems that the compilers usually implement `#include "path/file.h"` by firstly searching a path relative to the currently processed source file folder.

So the question is: how does it influence in practice the compilation time when using `#include` with quotes versus triangular brackets?

The question is only for the case when the `"path/to/file/filename.h"` is a relative path to the currently processed header, because otherwise it would behave similar to `#include <…>`.

It seems that the correctly set `#include "…"` should be faster for your own files than `#include <…>` in a large project (500 files or more).

**Edit**: Other questions about difference between `#include "…"` and `#include <…>` don't seem address compile time. Also, the standard is vague but most compilers do use `"…"` to search in the current folder first.

**Edit2** Reworded the title and the question. I'll accept the answer for any of these C++ compilers: Visual Studio, Intel, Clang, Gcc.

Comment: The standard simply says that the double quoted form may look in some different places for headers before looking for them in the same places as the angle-bracketed form looks in.  Otherwise, it is implementation defined where the headers are sought.  The difference in speed is unlikely to be measurable — and for many purposes, the notations are equivalent.  On the whole, it is better to use angle brackets for 'system defined' headers (e.g. C++ standard headers) and double quotes for 'user defined' headers, but it is mostly a nominal difference.

Comment: @Pierre: the other question discusses format of `#include` directives, but not the processing speed of the two forms.

Comment: Also, the question comes for a project that targets multiple platforms, and uses three different compilers - VS, clang, gcc. A coding standard requires use of triangular brackets for all includes (the "." must be among include folders).

Comment: Compilers tend to be configured to search through multiple directories to find a .h file when you use angle brackets.  So technically it could be slower.  The odds that it *measurably* slower is very remote, those directories get hot in the file system cache quickly.  After which file searches progresses at memory bus speeds, considerably less than the blink of an eye.  If this really matters then always take advantage of the compiler's pre-compiled header feature, you'll definitely notice that.

Comment: The subprojects do use the precompiled headers and they do list most dependency #include's from other subprojects or stl. This certainly helps a lot.

Comment: For what it's worth, a coding standard that requires angle brackets for all includes is, formally, stupid. Angle brackets are for system headers; there is no requirement that that syntax support files **at all**. A header can be some internal binary data in the compiler. Not that anybody does that, but quoted names will always work, both for header **files** (yours and the system's) as well as system headers that aren't files.

Comment: @Pete Becker Here is a link to one http://www.stroustrup.com/JSF-AV-rules.pdf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename